# Facebook Send Button - How to pass generated PHP variable in url

Tags: php, facebook, url, post, sendmessage

I am currently coding a website where lines of information are drawn from a database and displayed using PHP coding (about 20 pieces of info per page).  I have included the javascript SDK for facebook after the head and generated the div tag for the send button for each piece of information.  My intention is to have a user click the send-button for a specific line of information and transmit the url for only that info - not the main page.

Using php coding I have changed the data-href URL in the fb-send div to represent the referenced information and pass the php variable through the URL.  While the URL tests correctly it is not being represented when the send button is clicked (it only references the main page).

Is it possible to pass PHP variables through the URL of the send button?
If so, how can I do this?
If not, what are other options to achieve my desired outcome?

Please let me know if my problem is unclear! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$url_view = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . getenv('REQUEST_URI');

$facebook = 
    "<div class='socialshare_fb'>
        <iframe scrolling='no' style='border-width: initial; border-color: initial; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 20px; width: 90px; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial;' title='Share on Facebook.' src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=".$url_view."&action=like&amp;layout=button_count&amp;locale=pt_PT &amp;node_type=link&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90'>
        </iframe>
    </div>";
echo $facebook;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried this and continued to have similar problems.  In testing across browsers I found it unique to Google Chrome.  I have yet to fix this trick - but appreciate the help!